# Кастомизированный NavigationItem

Tags: swift

Как сделать подобный navigationItem? 
Присваиваю titleview = uiimageview, но она не такого размера. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не NavigationItem. Вы можете реализовать подобное несколькими способами. Наиболее популярный - так называемый, parallax header. Есть множество готовых библиотек, с помощью которых можете легко сделать подобное и с дополнительными плюшками:

https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader
https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader

Можете сами реализовать подобное разными способами, подходящими под Ваш дизайн/запросы:

- Сделать его backgroundView у UITableView и следить за contentOffset для обновления положения
- Сделать header'ом/ячейкой таблицы и следить за изменением contentOffset если что-то нужно обновить визуально
- Если не надо его скроллить - просто отдельной UIView.